# Meteor on client side and Express on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, meteor

As a basic description of the stack to use, we're going to use meteor + angular on the client side of the application, while using express + mongodb (nodejs) on the server side. Of course, this idea could be absurd in an expert's perspective but let's just say the project is time constrained and we're trying to combine two components / both sides from different development cycles.

Being a non-expert on nodejs, my question is: Is it possible to run the meteor server simultaneously with the expressjs server?

How can I do that and what are the things I should keep in mind?

What problems will I surely encounter and how do I solve my way out of them?

Best practices would also be great help. :)

Comment: Are you sure you understood what meteor is? It sort of replaces all the things you are pointing out: MVC (angular), web application server (express); and it is both client and server. Other than that, yes, of course, you could run an express server alongside a meteor server, just use a different port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a "project that is time constrained", you are most likely to be able to finish it using Meteor alone, which already does all the things that your somewhat ad hoc collection of frameworks is supposed to do. Meteor alone on the client side doesn't make sense.

But to answer your question, Meteor already runs a Connect server, to which you can attach middleware instances (including Express) using the [`WebApp` package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/webapp). But there's absolutely no need to do this unless you want to run something outside the Meteor stack (such as https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs).